# How do I use less/css to affect only imgs within paragraphs with no other content?

Tags: html, css, css-float, less, jekyll

I am using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) to convert some blog posts from [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) format into HTML.
Some of the markdown content looks like this:

```
The previous paragraph.

![Img I want floated left of the content](xyz.jpg)Some text content to
flowed to the right of the image.

The next paragraph.
```

Jekyll translates this to (approximately):

```
<p>
    The previous paragraph
</p>
<p>
    <img src="xyz.jpg">Some text content to be flowed to the right of the
    image.
</p>
```

Other markdown content looks like this:

```
The previous paragraph.

![Img I want in its own standlone paragraph not floated](abc.jpg)

The next paragraph.
```

Jekyll translates this to (approximately):

```
<p>
    The previous paragraph
</p>
<p>
    <img src="abc.jpg">
</p>
<p>
    The next paragraph
</p>
```

This is logical, but doesn't entirely work for my purposes, because I want to
apply some CSS styling to the first type of image so that it floats left of
the text, so the text wraps around (in fact, I think I want to apply
approximately `float: left; margin-right: 1em;`), but not the second type.

*(Currently my CSS styling has float set to the default, which means the first
category of images do not float left of the paragraph, even though that's the
implication of the markdown).*

Is there a way to apply some CSS styling to `<img>`s that only appear inside a
`<p>` with no other content next to them? I am using [less](http://lesscss.org/), if that helps.

Alternatively, is there some other way to fix my problem?

I definitely need to consider the input markdown an invariant - it's being
generated by an automated process I cannot reasonably change. I would prefer
not to modify Jekyll also (although I am willing to entertain that possibility
as an answer).

Answer (score 0):

Does the `:only-child` pseudo-class work?

```
p > img:only-child{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

Comment: @AndrewFerrier I'm pretty sure that `:only-child` [will ignore](https://jsfiddle.net/35yYJ/93/) text nodes as well as `:first-child`, etc. Therefore all images within paragraphs will be selected even in the presence of text nodes.

Comment: @HashemQolami you are quite right. This does only work for nodes that have non-text nodes as children, so strictly speaking this answer isn't correct. In my case I am lucky; my problem is more precise and I don't care about text nodes in my case. It's still helpful, but I'm de-marking it as "correct".